# Python Multiprocessing write to csv data for huge volume files

Tags: python, pandas, multithreading, performance, multiprocessing

I am trying to do calculation and write it to another txt file using multiprocessing program. I am getting count mismatch in output txt file. every time execute I am getting different output count.

I am new to python could some one please help.

```
import pandas as pd
import multiprocessing as mp

source = "\\share\usr\data.txt"
target = "\\share\usr\data_masked.txt"

Chunk = 10000

def process_calc(df):
    ''' 
        get source df do calc and return newdf
        ...
    '''
 return(newdf)        
  
def calc_frame(df):
    output_df = process_calc(df)
    output_df.to_csv(target,index=None,sep='|',mode='a',header=False)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    reader= pd.read_table(source,sep='|',chunksize = chunk,encoding='ANSI')
    pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())
    jobs = []
    
    for each_df in reader:
        process = mp.Process(target=calc_frame,args=(each_df)
        jobs.append(process)
        process.start()
    
    for j in jobs:
        j.join()
```

Comment: Probably the issue is just that multiple processes are writing to the same file at the same time.  It's probably better to write to individual files and then `cat` all the files together.

Comment: The code you posted has many compilation and semantic errors. This cannot possibly execute at all.

Comment: @Booboo: I apologies for the compilation and semantic errors, Since I drafted it in notepad. Your solution was simple and works perfectly as expected.
Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several issues in your source as posted that would prevent it from even compiling let alone running. I have attempted to correct those in an effort to also solving your main problem. But do check the code below thoroughly just to make sure the corrections make sense.

First, the *args* argument to the `Process` constructor should be specified as a `tuple`. You have specified `args=(each_df)`, but `(each_df)` is *not* a `tuple`, it is a simple parenthesized expression; you need `(each_df,)` to make if a `tuple` (the statement is also missing a closing parentheses).

The problem you have in addition to making no provision against multiple processes simultaneously attempting to append to the same file is that you cannot be assured of the order in which the processes complete and thus you have no real control over the order in which the dataframes will be appended to the csv file.

The solution is to use a processing pool with the [`imap` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=pool%20imap#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.imap). The *iterable* to pass to this method is just the `reader`, which when iterated returns the next dataframe to process. The return value from `imap` is an *iterable* that when iterated will return the next return value from `calc_frame` *in task-submission order*, i.e. the same order that the dataframes  were submitted. So as these new, modified dataframes are returned, the main process can simply append these to the output file one by one:

```py
import pandas as pd
import multiprocessing as mp

source = r"\\share\usr\data.txt"
target = r"\\share\usr\data_masked.txt"

Chunk = 10000

def process_calc(df):
    ''' 
        get source df do calc and return newdf
        ...
    '''
    return(newdf)

def calc_frame(df):
    output_df = process_calc(df)
    return output_df

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with mp.Pool() as pool:
        reader = pd.read_table(source, sep='|', chunksize=Chunk, encoding='ANSI')
        for output_df in pool.imap(process_calc, reader):
            output_df.to_csv(target, index=None, sep='|', mode='a', header=False)
```